# Javascript does not stop submit to server after validation

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

i am trying to do a form validation using javascript. if error was found the javascript should stop sending the form to the server.

i made sure that the javascript returns false by writing the statement :
    return false;

and still the form is sent to the server .

script tag:

```
<script language="javascript" src="validations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my form tag:

```
FORM id="frm" name="newCustomer" METHOD="POST" ACTION="register.php" onsubmit="return validateNewCustomer()">
```

JavaScript function :

```
function validateNewCustomer() {
    var name = document.getElementById('f_name').value;

    var okCustomer = true;

    if (name.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('f_name').value="kossetak";
        document.getElementById('errfname').innerHTML = "Error Name";
        okCustomer = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errname').innerHTML = "";
        okCustomer = true;
    }

    return okCustomer;
}
```

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the Javascript function `validateNewCustomer()`?

Comment: Where are you returning `false`? Show all relevant code, please.

Comment: is there any error in firebug ? Maybe your javascript has errors, and false is not returned, so the form submit

Comment: does the validateNewCustomer() return true?

Comment: @Robin Maben im returning false just for testing...i'll post the code now

Comment: The form HTML may be helpful also. Maybe the problem isn't the `return false` but your validation function isn't working properly.

Comment: Where on earth do they teach this "temporary value to defer the `return` until the end of the function" stuff? That's just hilarious.

Comment: i've tried using an empty function with the statement return false , and it stops...it seems the problem is in the Javascript code

Comment: @user: So go look at the debugger.

Comment: @NiklasB. if you look closely , i do this so that all error messages appear, i've only shown a small part of this function, got it? :)

Comment: Validation should never use true by default. it should always be false unless all checks have been made and your errors is still empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You always return true from your function, because `name.value == ""` is always false, so you enter the else clause.

Notice that you already have `.value` on this line:

```
var name = document.getElementById('f_name').value
```

So when you say `name.value` you are accessing `document.getElementById('f_name').value.value` which will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider submitting the form inside your JavaScript function rather than using the HTML action parameter.

An example of this would be:

```
<form id="frm" name="newCustomer" onsubmit="return validateNewCustomer()">...</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateNewCustomer() {
    var name = document.getElementById('f_name').value;

    var okCustomer = true;

    // name.value replaced to name
    if (name == "") {
        document.getElementById('f_name').value="kossetak";
        document.getElementById('errfname').innerHTML = "Error Name";
        okCustomer = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errname').innerHTML = "";
        // Submit the document here
        document.forms["newCustomer"].submit();
        // Still supply a return value in case you need it later
        okCustomer = true;
    }

    return okCustomer;
}
```